# Using Square API to automate orders

Tags: api, updates, square-connect

Is there some way to use Square API's to complete order processing or can that only be done manually on the website. It looks like to me that Square only has Read only access and no way to update the order status through the API

Pretty big deal since having to do it manually is very time consuming and slows the process down from handling hundreds of orders per hour down to a few a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Management of Square Market orders is now possible with the Square Connect API. The [List Orders](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api#get-orders) endpoint provides a list of all of a merchant's Square Market orders, and the [Update Order](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api#put-orderid) endpoint lets a merchant programmatically update an order's status to completed, canceled, or refunded.

See [Managing orders](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api#managingorders) for more information.

Comment: That would be HUGEEEE step, if I can get a TOUCHLESS way to handle and manage my orders I can look to permanently move away from Paypal to Square. But TOUCHLESS is VERY important since the entire setup today is automated and efficient.

Comment: Does the Square Connect API cover the Invoices generation ? I tried looking at the documentation but that didn't help ...